# Trying to access html element in a view from controller in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to access html element of a view from Controller in asp.net Mvc.
In login form after filling data in username and password textbox. Posting it through Http Post and accessing it in controller and now based on condition in controller i want to manipulate html element in same view from where it is getting data.

view

```
<span id="spanInvalidCredentialsMessage" style="display:none">
  <div class="row form-group">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-danger">
    Your credentials could not be authenticated. Please try again.
  </div>
  </div>
   <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <hr class="alert-danger" />
     </div>
    </div>
    </span>
```

login form field in view

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user text-primary">
</span>Username
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  @Html.TextBox("txtBxUsername", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.TextBox("txtBxPassword", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
<input id="btnLogin" type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
</div>
```

Controller section getting login details through httppost

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(FormCollection form)
{
//Invoke the method to authenticate the user credentials. txtBxUsername.Text.Trim().ToUpper()
string msgUserAuthenticated=objADService.GenericIsAuthenticatedWithMessage("ABC", form["txtBxUsername"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper(),form["txtBxPassword"].ToString());
  //Check if the user was authenticated.
 if (msgUserAuthenticated.Equals("Authenticated", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == true)
 {
   //Set the Session Variable and Redirect to the Home Page ASPX.
   Session[CommonConstants.SESSION_USER_ID] = form["txtBxUsername"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
   Session[CommonConstants.SESSION_USER_DOMAIN] = form["txtBxPassword"].ToString();
    //Redirect the user to the home page                
    //Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
  return View("Home");            
   }
   else
    {
    //Show the error message.
   spanInvalidCredentialsMessage.Visible = true;
    //Clear the text boxes for Username and Password.
     txtBxUsername.Text = "";
     txtBxPassword.Text = "";
     return View("Login");
      }
}
```

Expected if wrong username & password would be there then in controller i can access html element id in view and display it.
actual
no idea how to achieve

Comment: It's not quite clear what are you trying to do and what is the problem. But in general you cannot access any parts of the views in your controller. You have access only to the form data which is sent within a http request(`txtBxUsername` and `txtBxPassword`) in your case.

Comment: You can't access an already rendered HTML element from the controller. This is not how a website works. Controller code runs on a server somewhere in a data center, HTML website is displayed on a client computer somewhere else. So what you have to do in the controller is use a ViewModel (not FormCollection), set the properties you want in this model, use the model to render a new HTML page or fragment, then serve it to the client computer. Totally different interaction model than a windows forms application. See [MVC Architecture Tutorial](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/mvc-architecture)

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/difference-between-mvc-and-web-forms/